# In graalpython what is difference between `ginstall` and `pip`?

Tags: python, graalvm, graalpython

In `graalpython` https://www.graalvm.org/python/ what is difference between `ginstall` and `pip`? Which one to use?

Comment: According to [their docs](https://www.graalvm.org/reference-manual/python/Packages/) it looks like ``ginstall`` is for packages made explicitly compatible with GraalVM (i.e. extension modules like ``numpy``) whereas ``pip`` allows you to pull in regular modules, which may-or-may-not work (i.e. its a gamble for extension modules). Haven't tried it myself, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These days `pip` is the recommended way to install packages in GraalPy (formerly GraalPython).

The `pip` bundled in GraalPy prefers versions of packages that are known to work on GraalPy, but honors the user specified version, i.e., `pip install x` will install version of `x` known to work with GraalPy. `pip install x=1.2.3` will just install version `1.2.3` no matter if it is known to work with GraalPy (it may still work, but we haven't tested it). On top of that the GraalPy `pip` patches some well known packages to be more compatible with GraalPy.

---

Old answer applicable to older versions of GraalPython:

Unlike `pip`, `ginstall` installs package versions that are known to be (mostly) compatible with GraalPython and always runs `setup.py` to install the package from sources.

Both `pip` and `ginstall` apply GraalPython specific patches for some packages. This application of the patches is in `pip` achieved by monkey patching its internals, so it may not work with never versions of `pip`.

TL;DR: I would use `ginstall` first. If it does not support the package you want, I'd use `pip`. Also, avoid upgrading the bundled `pip` if possible.

Historically, another reason for the existence of `ginstall` was that GraalPython did not support SSL, which `pip` needs unless you use custom mirror. This not the case anymore.